# Issue building xcode Project for real Device

Tags: xcode, opencv

I have one problem and it`bothering me for a while. I`m usning opencv framework from template project which i have founded on internet: http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/download/

I need opencv function for comparing two images, so i need to convert UIImage to Iplmage in order to use it in function. However, everything builds fine on simulator, but, when i connect ipad 2 device (i need it because i`m using camera in application) compiler throws me error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>    "_cvCreateImage", referenced from:
>        +[SomeViewController CreateIplImageFromUIImage:] in SomeViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

I try installing xcode 4.2, i have downgraded it to xcode 4.1, no success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the openCV library to your project? It's a linker issue.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV build you're using is pretty old and intended to work with iOS3+4. I guess going with a newer Version which supports iOS5 is a good idea :)

Take a look at [this Version](https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone). Just grab a copy, setup iPad-support and you're good to go (tested it).